# Python dictionaries-How to keep the new value from overwriting the previous value?

Tags: python, nested, dictionary

I want to create a Dictionary called "First" (as in First Name) that will store numerous first names which are all stored in the dictionary  via a function. The idea is that the dictionary can support multiple names,

so here is my problem:

When I add a name to the dictionary, then I go to add a second one via the function, the previous name is overwritten by the last. How do I mend this? I know it involves something like a dictionary within a dictionary, or nested conditionals. Here is my code:

```
def store(data,value):
    data['Names'] = {}
    data['Names']['first'] = {}
    data['Names']['first'] = {value}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen instead of overwriting the old value?

Answer (score 4):

Turn `data['Names']['first']` in a list and append to it:

```
data['Names'] = {}
data['Names']['first'] = []

def store(data, value):
    data['Names']['first'].append(value)
```

Comment: And if `{value}` was a Python 3 set, `data['Names'] = set()` and `add` instead of `append` is also an option. And `data['Names'] = defaultdict(set)` is also an option, it makes the initialization of every element of names with `set()` unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Python < 2.5 doesn't have `defaultdict`, however you can achieve the same thing in with ordinary `dict` too.

```
>>> names = {}
>>> name_list = [('Jon', 'Skeet'), ('Jeff', 'Atwood'), ('Joel', 'Spolsky')]
>>> for first, last in name_list:
        names.setdefault('first', []).append(first)
        names.setdefault('last', []).append(last)
>>> print names
{'first': ['Jon', 'Jeff', 'Joel'], 'last': ['Skeet', 'Atwood', 'Spolsky']}
```

`setdefault` returns the existing value if the key already exists in dict, or sets the new value and returns the newly set value if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html). Then you can do things like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data['Names'] = defaultdict(list) # Or pass set instead of list.
data['Names']['first'].append("Bob")
data['Names']['first'].append("Jane")
data['Names']['last'].extend("T", "Mart")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be storing the list of names as a list, rather than a dictionary. So you would have:

```
data['Names'] = {}
data['Names']['first'] = [] #note the brackets here instead of curlies
data['Names']['first'] = [value1, value2]
```

To add one after instantiation, you can do:

```
data['Names']['first'].append(another_first_name)
```

Lists are zero-indexed, so to get the 1st first name, you can say:

```
data['Names']['first'][0]
```

Comment: `()` creates a tuple, not a list. Tuples are immutable and thus not usable for this. Use a list, i.e. use `[]` instead of `()`

Comment: That's what I get for commenting at 3:30am. Thanks for the face slap; I fixed the post.

Comment: Hmm? Sure you can use tuples: `data['Names']['first'] += (another_first_name,)` :)