# Python: My dictionary that stores first names won't store more than one first name at a time

Tags: python, function, dictionary

So, I've created a Dictionary that stores first-names as a list within that dictionary. New names are added within the dictionary's list via a function. Now, this is where i have hit a snag:

**Main Obstacle:**  *The function overwrites new names that I add. If I add the name "George" to the list via the function, it will store the name "George". But, I want to add the name "Alfred" within the dictionary, it overwrites the name "George" and adds the name "Alfred".*

I am sure you can see how problematic this is for someone who wants to add multiple names to the dictionary's list. The odd thing is that  when I type out the exact same code into the interpreter and I individually append names to the dictionary's list, it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
def add(data,value):

data['names'] = {}
data['names']['first'] = []
data['names']['first'].append(value)
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841868/python-dictionaries-how-to-keep-the-new-value-from-overwriting-the-previous-value

Comment: umm, can you show us your exact code? What you're inputting, what you're getting, and why you expect something different?

Answer (score 4):

Didn't you ask this question already? ([My previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841868/python-dictionaries-how-to-keep-the-new-value-from-overwriting-the-previous-value/4843242#4843242))

You are **always** setting the `data['names']` to an empty dictionary before appending value to it.

```
def add(data, value):
    data.setdefault('names', {}).setdefault('first', []).append(value)
```

See python docs on [`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Comment: are you proposing this for the body of the function? Why not just define the items ahead of time and save two calls to `setdefault`, a construction of two lists and end up with easier to read code?

Comment: Yeah, I did propose it for function body.